# How to pass json to render_to_response

Tags: python, json, django

I am trying to pass a json file through render_to_response to the front end. The front end is not a django template, its coded in JS, HTML etc. I am getting some weird error. Can anybody help me with that. I am attaching the code and the traceback.

```
return render_to_response('ModelView.html', json.dumps(newDict))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 128, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\PythonWorkspace\ScApp\ScApp2\views.py", line 78, in ScorecardApp20
    return render_to_response('ModelView.html', json.dumps(newDict))
  File "C:\Users\kxc89\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 27, in render_to_response
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, using=using)
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 59, in render
    context = make_context(context, request, autoescape=self.backend.engine.autoescape)
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\context.py", line 274, in make_context
    raise TypeError('context must be a dict rather than %s.' % context.__class__.__name__)
TypeError: context must be a dict rather than str.
```

Comment: That error message is crystal clear.  `render_to_response` is for rendering an html template with a dict of context data.  If that's not what you want, then you're using the wrong function in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don’t use `render_to_response`, it’s obsolete. Use `render` instead.

```
return render(request, 'ModelView.html', {'new_dict': json.dumps(newDict)})
```

The third argument has to be a dictionary, so you can either add the json string to the dictionary as I have done above, or perhaps you don’t want to use `json.dumps()` at all and just use `newDict`.

Comment: The presumption that the `ModelView.html` template accepts a json serialized obj as the value of a template var called "new_dict" is so far-fetched that this is downvotable.

Comment: If I pass a dict then is it possible to work with it in a javascript? The javascript should parse the json and then update a dropdown in the ModelView.html. Is there a better way to do it? ModelView.html is not a django template, its a normal static HTML5 file.

Comment: @KChow it's hard to answer your question because you haven't shown any code, only the error message. If `ModelView.html` is not a template, then it doesn't make sense to render it. Perhaps you can use [`JsonResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects), e.g, `return JsonResponse(newDict)`.

Comment: What I am basically trying to do is when the login is done, it should send a static page where a dropdown will be automatically filled with values from a database.

Comment: I can't help any more because you haven't shown any code.

Comment: How do I access newDict using javascript from the ModelView.html? Is there a way to do that? Which part of the code do you need?

Comment: It sounds like you need a view that returns json, and a URL pattern for that view. Then your JavaScript can make an ajax request to fetch the json.

Answer (score -1):

Use the code below

```
import json
data = open('/static/JsonFile.json').read() #opens the json file and saves the raw contents
JsonData = json.dumps(data) #converts to a json structure
context = {'obj': JsonData}
return render(request, 'templates', context)
```

Hope it should work !

Comment: If I pass a dict then is it possible to work with it in a javascript? The javascript should parse the json and then update a dropdown in the ModelView.html. Is there a better way to do it? ModelView.html is not a django template, its a normal static HTML5 file.